# Wordpress randomize quote function not showing any output

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field('quote'); 
    //$rows now contains all the quotes that have been added. 

    $rand_row = $rows[ array_rand( $rows ) ];
    //Puts all the rows from $rows in an array and randomly selects a single row.

    $rand_row_quote = $rand_row['quote'];
    $rand_row_auteur = $rand_row['naam_auteur']; 
    //Gets the values from the subfields. 

    $quote = get_field( $rand_row_auteur, $rand_row_quote );
    //Puts the values in a single variable. 

    echo $quote;
    //Echo's the values of each row.
?>
```

So I've added the above code into ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) in Wordpress. I've made several subfields which I respectively called quote and `naam_auteur` (name of the author in English). They are contained in a field called `quote`.

Now when I enter the above PHP code to show my random quote with their author, but it is blank.

Any ideas or suggestions?

---

The code that solved my issue is below here:

```
    <?php
        $rows = get_field('quotes');
        $row_count = count($rows);
        $i = rand(0, $row_count - 1);
    ?>
    <p>Quotes van de fans:</p>
    <h2><?php echo $rows[ $i ]['quote']; ?></h2>
    <h3><?php echo $rows[ $i ]['naam_auteur']; ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACF function `get_field()` accepts only one parameter, you pass two. Also make sure that the variable you pass to the function **is** actually a field name.

Retrieving a field as a variable is done like this:

```
<?php

$variable = get_field('field_name');

// do something with $variable

?>
```

If your field contain multiple sub-fields, [read this manual](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/) on how to show them.

Comment: Thanks your link turned out to make me realize that i made a mistake in my code. I'll edit my question to add the final code. Thanks for the help.